# Get MouseEvent from overlapped UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mouseevent

I have trouble with my MouseEvents in WPF/C#.
I got some simple WPF structure:

```
<Grid Name="ID1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <customUserControl:CustomUserControl:Name="MainDisplay" UseDefaultContextMenu="False" Grid.Row="0">
        <customUserControl:CustomUserControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Thing1" Click="Click1"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Thing2" Click="Click2"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Thing3" Click="Click3"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Thing4" Click="Click4"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </customUserControl:CustomUserControl.ContextMenu>
    </customUserControl:CustomUserControl>
    <Overlay1:OverlayS Name="Overlay_One" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

As you may see I got standard Grid with two overlapping UserControls.
When rigth-click on CustomUserControl I get access to the ContextMenu.
The Overlay1 does show an overlay with transparent background. Still when this is displayed, I don't have access to the MouseEvents of customUserControl anymore. But that would be required.

My idea now was to simply implement an togglebutton to switch between MouseEvents on CustomUserControl or Overlay1 with both still displayed at the same time.

Comment: You can use the [Mouse Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse?view=net-5.0) to subscribe to mouse events globally, and then filter the event source and handle the event if the source matches the overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by-pass all the events catched by OverlayS to the control you need like:

```cs
  private void OverlayS_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                 
                if (!e.Handled)
                {
                   // e.Handled = true; //Set to true only when the mouse event must end here
                    var eventArg = new RoutedEventArgs(e.RoutedEvent);                    
                    eventArg.Source = sender;
                    var otherUIControl = CustomUserControl as UIElement;
                    otherUIControl.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
                }  
        }
```

For other mouse events (previewMouseDown, MouseWheel, etc) you will have to create the appropiate EventArgs. For example:

```cs
       private void OverlayS_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Handled)
            {
                // e.Handled = true;//Set to true only when the mouse event must end here
                 var eventArg = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice,e.Timestamp, e.ChangedButton);
                eventArg.RoutedEvent = e.RoutedEvent; 
                eventArg.Source = sender;               
                var otherUIControl = CustomUserControl as UIElement;
                otherUIControl.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
            }
        }
```

Probably, you don't have to copy the EventArgs and just pass them on to otherUiControl.

```cs
  private void OverlayS_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                 
                if (!e.Handled)
                {                    
                    var otherUIControl = CustomUserControl as UIElement;
                    otherUIControl.RaiseEvent(e);
                }  
        }
```

But be carefull as some mouse events might reach many controls and they can mess with e.Handled.

Comment: You should only set a routed event to handled if _really_ necessary. It's best to allow other elements in the tree to handle the event.

Comment: @BionicCode, yes, right. Noted and edited :)